# Is it possible to get XMLGregorianCalendar directly from MyBATIS?

Tags: java, mybatis

I work with public StackOverflow dump and have everything stored in MySQL. Now, I want to perform some analyses using Java and MyBATIS. For some of these I need to extract timeseries for a user, or a particular question etc. So for this, lets say posts and their timestamps, I have a MyBatis query:

```
 <select id="GetAllPostsTimeStamps" resultType="java.util.Date">
     SELECT creationDate from posts
 </select>
```

which hands the timestamp data to MyBatis ResultHandler, where I do this transformation:

```
@Override
public void handleResult(ResultContext context) {
   TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
   TimeZone.setDefault(tz);
   Date tstamp = (Date) context.getResultObject();
   XMLGregorianCalendar xmlTstam = Tstamp.makeTimestamp(tstamp.getTime());
   ...etc...
}
```

I really need to use `XMLGregorianCalendar` because all my downstream logic relies on this type.

Is it possible to tell MyBatis with its handlers feature to make transformation of SQL datetime to XMLGregorianCalendar internally (i.e. I will code the handler only once), so I will get proper timestamps out of it everytime I need?

Editing to add more clarity.

So, when I save java objects with `XMLGregorianCalendar` fields into DB (MySQL datetime type) I use an implementation of MyBatis handler:

```
XMLGregorianCalendarDateTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<XMLGregorianCalendar>
...
```

which I specify in the `INSERT` query like this:

```
    ..., #{creationDate,
           javaType=javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar,
           jdbcType=TIMESTAMP,                
           typeHandler=...XMLGregorianCalendarTypeHandler},...
```

is there a way to specify the backward transform handler for `SELECT` type queries?

Answer (score 1):

I found why it wasnt working, maybe it will help somebody:

So, when I configure a handler specifying both types: JDBC and Java, this doesnt work:

```
<typeHandler javaType="javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar" 
      jdbcType="TIMESTAMP"
      handler="my.package.XMLGregorianCalendarTimestampTypeHandler" />
```

But if I specify just Java type it works. Magic:

```
<typeHandler javaType="javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar" 
      handler="my.package.XMLGregorianCalendarTimestampTypeHandler" />
```

Not sure if it is a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MyBatis, but will this help?

```
DatatypeFactory factory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar calendar = factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar();
calendar.setMillisecond(tstamp.getTime());
```

Comment: it is very similar to what I do, however I need a handler in order to handle the DATETIME to XMLGregorianCalendar. I figured it, so I'll post an answer for my own question.